# flv movie is not working?

Tags: flash, joomla

I am not able to play flv movie on the sever it gives an error :

`GET http://sagebridgedigital.com/client/michelangelos/index.php/Clear_Skin_1.swf 404 (Not Found)` in chrome.

Whereas skin is on the root of the site
[Here is the url](http://sagebridgedigital.com/client/michelangelos/index.php/asparagus-alla-domenico)

Without sef these videos are working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is probably not stored at that path not the server - which is what the HTTP 404 not found error means.

Also you seem to be accessing the file incorrectly - the path might not include index.php

This seems to work : http://sagebridgedigital.com/client/michelangelos/Clear_Skin_1.swf

Comment: What changes should i do in object tag so that it can take path without index.php?

Answer (score 0):

i just navigated to your site and tried this url ...

http://sagebridgedigital.com/client/michelangelos/index.php/Clear_Skin_1.swf

and it worked (i think, as my ipad can't dowload it)